# Can I modify "tools" namespace?

Tags: android, namespaces

I using tools namespace in Android Studio (`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`). I know all about using of this namespace, but that's not enough for me. I want to modify this namespace. For example `RecyclerView` has `tools:listitem` attribute. That's great, but I also use `ViewPager` and it has no analog for this task (for example `tools:pageitem`).

Can I create new tools-attributes and invent behaviour for them? I need it to visualise some views work in layout-designer.

Comment: did you try it? i think you can.

Comment: I want to try, but I don't know how to modify namespace and create my own attributes. I even don't know, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I create new tools-attributes and invent behaviour for them?

If you build your own IDE, then yes.

If you are willing to maintain some fork of Android Studio, then yes.

If you get a job with Google, can work on Android Studio, and can convince them to add in your desired behavior, then yes.

If Google accepts code contributions to Android Studio, and you can convince them to add in your desired behavior, then yes.

Otherwise, AFAIK, what you want is not possible. Android Studio is not really end-user-programmable in that way.